# Wordpress complex portfolio page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've hired a Wordpress programmer for coding my site in wordpress. I'm using a year slider on portfolio page where one can sort projects within certain range eg 2004 to 2007, 2005 to 2009 etc. He is using posts to publish project details and earlier suggested to use post date as published date, which isn't entirely true and I wasn't comfortable with.

He's looking for another solution where he can filter projects within a range, rather by type, category or just single date. He is stuck on it from a week. I started hunting for examples where a wordpress site is performing that functionality but all in vain. Can someone please suggest a possible solution or an idea that he can try? I'm not very technical in php/coding, a high level concept would be good. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [Pods CMS](http://podscms.org/).  It lets you add custom content types to WordPress.  Using Pods, you could create a custom content type called `project` and give it properties like `published_date` or `type`.  You could then create a Portfolio page that displays `project` items while offering sorting options that will sort the items according to any of the properties.

[Here's an example site](http://skcdev.com/portfolio/) that I found in the [showcase](http://podscms.org/showcase/) on the Pods website.  Each project includes properties like a title, screenshot, a list of technologies it uses, and a description.  At the top of the page, you can filter projects by type of project or type of work.  Using Pods, you can do this sort of thing.  In your case, instead of filtering by type of project or type of work, you can filter by year.

Answer (score 1):

All of the post/page meta data can be used to sort results in the wordpress loop. As well your programmer could use variable post tag, or just use a custom variable in the custom meta data for each post or page.

[Custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) are extremely powerful, and I think that they would be the best solution to sort and categorize your projects in your portfolio.

:)

Comment: Thanks Kory. He is already using custom fields to sort the project. Infact, I've added lot of meta data like project name, awards etc with custom fields. The problem is not categorization but filtering within a range. Any other cues?